# Generalized Cassini oval and Manipulate

Tags: plotting, manipulate, button

I've created a visualization of Generalized Cassini oval using *Manipulate* with two options: random and regular. The former generates pseudorandom points in a plane, whereas the latter generates points in a plane that correspond to vertices of a regular polygon.

Furthermore, user can manipulate with the total number of points in a plane. I would like the following feature: if a user picks the regular option and then changes the total number of points, it stays in the regular mode.

I would appreciate any help tackling this issue. Here is my code.

```
Manipulate[pts = PadRight[pts, n, RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {10, 2}]]; 
 Show[Graphics[Point[pts], PlotRange -> All], 
  Graphics[ContourPlot[Product[SquaredEuclideanDistance[{x, y}, pts[[i]]], {i, 1, 
  Length[pts]}] == a^2, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
    ContourStyle -> col, PlotPoints -> m]]], {m, 5, 50, 5}, {a, 0, 
  10}, {col, Red}, {n, 3, 10, 1}, {{pts, {{0, 0}}}, Locator}, 
 Button["Regular", pts = CirclePoints[n]], 
 Button["Random", pts = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {n, 2}]]]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with buttons, but need to keep track of the state. The logic is: if the mode is regular and the n-value changes, then keep the mode.

```
Manipulate[If[n =!= nold && reg == True, pts = CirclePoints[n]]; 
  pts = PadRight[pts, n, RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {10, 2}]];
  Show[Graphics[Point[pts], PlotRange -> All], 
  Graphics[ContourPlot[
  Product[SquaredEuclideanDistance[{x, y}, pts[[i]]], {i, 1, 
   Length[pts]}] == a^2, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
  ContourStyle -> col, PlotPoints -> m]]], {m, 5, 50, 5}, 
  {a, 0, 10}, {col, Red}, {n, 3, 10, 1}, {{pts, {{0, 0}}}, Locator}, 
 Button["Regular", pts = CirclePoints[n]; reg = True;], 
 Button["Random", reg = False; pts = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {n, 2}]], 
 Initialization :> (nold = 0;)]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Now, the code works exactly the way I imagined it.

Answer (score 0):

Use a control instead of buttons. E.g. {"name",{possible values...} and use `TrackeSymbols`:

```
Manipulate[pts = PadRight[pts, n, RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {10, 2}]];
 If[mode == "Random", pts = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {n, 2}], 
  pts = CirclePoints[n]]; 
 Show[Graphics[Point[pts], PlotRange -> All], 
  Graphics[ContourPlot[
    Product[SquaredEuclideanDistance[{x, y}, pts[[i]]], {i, 1, 
       Length[pts]}] == a^2, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
    ContourStyle -> col, PlotPoints -> m]]]
 , {m, 5, 50, 5}, {a, 0, 10}, {col, Red}, {n, 3, 10, 
  1}, {{pts, {{0, 0}}}, 
  Locator}, {{mode, "Random", "Mode:"}, {"Random", "Regular"}}, 
 TrackedSymbols :> {m, a, col, n, mode}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It solves the problem I had, however, now when I change the value of a, the points also change position.